# AS3 and HTTPS - opening a raw socket, loading assets via HTTP?

Tags: actionscript-3, facebook, security, sockets, https

in the light of facebook's imminent switch to HTTPS (yes, i'm late to the party),
i have some questions around AS3 and HTTPS / HTTP.

so my understanding is that facebook is going to serve up html from an https address,
and in the html is an iframe with the URL of our .swf file.

i assume that we'll have to be able to server that .swf file via https, and that seems reasonable.

my questions are more around what happens within flash once the .swf is running.
we have many requests to our backend via HTTP, and we also periodically open up a raw socket also into our backend.

is flash/the browser going to give us grief about that socket or those http requests ?

thanks in advance,
orion

Comment: All I can say is start making sure all your socket error handling is intact and working.

Comment: indeed. I'm also wondering if requests from Facebook to our backend (ie, not via the user's browser) need to go over HTTPS.